# Install and configure xl2tpd server side by side strongswan

Tags: debian, vpn, xl2tpd

I installed strongSwan 5.9.1 and working fine, I need to install xl2tpd side by side with running strongSwan service.

Please guide me to configure xl2tpd service step by step.

My OS is  *Debian 11.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you encountering issues?

Comment: And your tries are...?

Comment: i have used this scripts to install both in easy way ,https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have used this scripts to install both in easy way https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn

thanks all